# How to merge by date on R with a period between two years?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, merge, dataset

So I have this first dataset

| Company | Director | Dir_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | Alexander | 2014 |
| AB | Justin | 2020 |

We then understand that between 2014 and 2019, the director of AB was Alexander.

My second dataset is like that

| Company | Results | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AB | Good | 2014 |
| AB | Good | 2015 |
| AB | Bad | 2016 |

And so on for each year. I'd like to obtain this output by merging by company and date :

| Company | Results | Date | Director |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AB | Good | 2014 | Alexander |
| AB | Good | 2015 | Alexander |
| AB | Bad | 2016 | Alexander |

Comment: Either use fuzzy_join or tidyr::complete master and then join

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

On an extended sample, showing how to hardcode the other possible year values

```
df_m <- read.table(text = 'Company  Director    Dir_Date
AB  Alexander   2014
AB  Justin  2020', header = T)

df <- read.table(text = ' Company   Results Date
AB  Good    2014
AB  Good    2015
AB  Bad 2016
AB Something  2021', header = T)

library(tidyverse)
df %>% left_join(df_m %>% group_by(Company) %>% complete(Dir_Date = 2000:2021) %>%
                   fill(Director, .direction = 'down'),
                 by = c('Company' = 'Company', 'Date' = 'Dir_Date'))


  Company   Results Date  Director
1      AB      Good 2014 Alexander
2      AB      Good 2015 Alexander
3      AB       Bad 2016 Alexander
4      AB Something 2021    Justin
```

---

OR

```r
df_m <- read.table(text = 'Company  Director    Dir_Date
AB  Alexander   2014
AB  Justin  2020', header = T)

df <- read.table(text = ' Company   Results Date
AB  Good    2012
AB  Good    2015
AB  Bad 2016
AB Something  2021', header = T)

library(tidyverse)
df %>% left_join(df_m %>% group_by(Company) %>% complete(Dir_Date = 2000:2021) %>%
                   fill(Director, .direction = 'down'),
                 by = c('Company' = 'Company', 'Date' = 'Dir_Date'))
#>   Company   Results Date  Director
#> 1      AB      Good 2012      <NA>
#> 2      AB      Good 2015 Alexander
#> 3      AB       Bad 2016 Alexander
#> 4      AB Something 2021    Justin
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

---

```r
df_m <- read.table(text = 'Company  Director    Dir_Date
AB  Alexander   2014
AB  Justin  2020', header = T)

df <- read.table(text = ' Company   Results Date
AB  Good    2014
AB  Good    2015
AB  Bad 2016', header = T)

library(tidyverse)
df %>% left_join(df_m %>% group_by(Company) %>% complete(Dir_Date = seq(min(Dir_Date), max(Dir_Date), 1)) %>%
                   fill(Director, .direction = 'down'),
                 by = c('Company' = 'Company', 'Date' = 'Dir_Date'))
#>   Company Results Date  Director
#> 1      AB    Good 2014 Alexander
#> 2      AB    Good 2015 Alexander
#> 3      AB     Bad 2016 Alexander
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: This is what i get : Error in seq.default(min(.$Dir_Date), max(.$Dir_Date), 1) : 
  'from' must be a finite number

Comment: try without `.$`

Comment: I converted both date column with as.Date() but now i have this message (whatever the combination of .$ i try) : Error in seq.int(0, to0 - from, by) : 'to' must be a finite number

Comment: @theeconomista, you may have some NAs, try using `na.rm = T` in both min and max

Comment: I have no more error message but some trouble in the output concerning the director (lot of NAs that are added) even if the company and the results are merged well,  so i'll try to find where it comes from !

Comment: oh yes i understand where it comes from, sometimes, the director is still director nowadays, so for example we have : Company B ; James ; 2017 ; and from 2018 to 2021 i have NAs that are created

Comment: That's why I added `.$`  Still you may generate the sequence by hardcoding your possible minimum and max value. @theeconomista see edited answer please.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad, i didn't see the edit ! I still have some issues but it's not linked with your code i guess, more with the architecture of my data.